# Does it have bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $$f(x)= x+\sin x.$$

Does this function have bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$?

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The function is monotonic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; its derivative is bounded on the entire real line; $0<f'<2$

Comment: I assumed the OP is interested in subsets of the real line; I agree f' does take the values 0,2 , but I don't think that makes a difference here.